# read a mp3 file saved in cordava and the send it with websocket

Tags: cordova

I saved an mp3 file with cordova.media to the root of the android phone.

```
function recordAudio() {
    var src = "myrecording.mp3";
    var mediaRec = new Media(src,
    // success callback
    function() {
        console.log("recordAudio():Audio Success");
    },

    // error callback
    function(err) {
        console.log("recordAudio():Audio Error: "+ err.code);
    }
);

// Record audio
mediaRec.startRecord();

// Stop recording after 10 seconds
setTimeout(function() {
    mediaRec.stopRecord();
}, 10000);
}
```

When I try to read it with cordova.file I can't read from the root. ok, I should not save in the root, I tried to save with

```
 var src = cordova.file.dataDirectory +  "myrecording.mp3";
```

1. where can I find the file on the phone? I can open it with cordova file...
2. in onloadedend I get e:Progressevent, how can I decode the files to an json blob? I can access the mp3 data in result? how can I encode send via socket and decode it on the server side?

Comment: Check https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html, it tells you where you can read/write files.
Also check https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media, they give you example of where to read/write your files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, its simple,  I got it myself...

I read the mp3 files as URL

```
 reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

then send via websocket, on the nodejs server side I did

```
 var mp3Raw = jsonIn.mp3;
 var data = mp3Raw.replace(/^data:audio\/\w+;base64,/, ""); 
 var buf = new Buffer(data, 'base64');
```